Include section number when referencing subsection in another section, but not within the same
I'm modifying the numbering of sections and subsection (see MWE below), which somewhat messed up the referencing. What I'd like ideally is to have the section number (or letter in this case) included when referencing a subsection from another section (or subsection thereof), but not when referencing from another subsection within the same section.
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\arabic{subsection})}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}\label{mylabel}
Lorem ipsum.

\subsection{Second Subsection}
As mentioned in \ref{mylabel}, ... % This is fine

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
As mentioned in \ref{mylabel}, ... % This should show A.1

\end{document}

I tried using
\labelformat{subsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

which did result in including the section number ("A.1") in both referenced, but that's not entirely what I'm looking for, since the section number should, as mentioned, only be added when referencing "from the outside". I also thought about using an if statement in the \labelformat, but I don't know how I'd access the referencing section number (as opposed to the one being referenced)...
Additionally, I'd like to also get this to work with references to an \item using the enumitem package (again, basic stuff works, but same issue with section numbers), but that's a secondary goal.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Would you be willing to settle for a less ambitious objective: to include the section number/letter in all cross-references to subsection-level headers?

IMHO such abbreviations does not really make it easier for the reader. They are often even more dazzling.

@cabohah It might, if it were working. I tried to run the code from the answer there (just the MWE in a blank document) but get several errors ("Illegal parameter number in definition of \temp.", "Undefined control sequence.").
I terms of the stylistic choice behind the whole issue: The whole story is a bit more complicated (§ x Abs. y), I just abstracted it to a more simple level and would adapt any solution to what I actually need. Also, it's a requirement beyond my influence :)

So it seems to be a XY problem. Maybe package contract provides already what you need. It allows to refer to section, paragraph, sentence in legal texts.
